# how to cancel a previous requests when new request come from the same user in the same session

Tags: python, http, nginx, python-asyncio, aiohttp

We're building a rest api using aiohttp. Our app is designed so that user sending requests more frequently than receiving responses (because of time of calculation). For user is important the result of the latest request only. Is it possible to stop calculations on outdated requests?

Thank you

Comment: That rather violates one of the central tenets of HTTP. What if you wanted to scale that service to multiple servers behind a load balancer; then it gets extremely tricky cancelling requests which some other server may be handling. This is probably not the actual issue you should be trying to solve!

Comment: And what exactly does "cancel" mean? The server drops the connection?

Comment: After your rewrite: does this mean one HTTP request may take several ~minutes (?) to complete? That's also bad HTTP design; one request should be answered within a few seconds at most, the typical baseline target being 200ms. If you need longer running jobs, treat it as jobs: one HTTP request starts a background task and returns the task id. The client can then query about the job status using another HTTP request. E.g. `POST /tasks { params }`, `GET /tasks/42`. Obviously such background tasks can be cancelled via any mechanism that makes sense in your backend.

Comment: we're targeting 5-10 sec for now.

Comment: Too long for an HTTP request. Accept a new "job request" per `POST /tasks`, start a background task independent of the web server, return a new resource id. Have the client query the new resource for results/status (`GET /tasks/42`). Cancel the task if a new one supersedes it; the client can be aware of this implicit cancellation and doesn't need to query the old resource anymore.

Comment: thank you @deceze, I think I understood your point

Comment: @Drizzt1991 I don't want to copy paste your answer from google group but I believe it must be here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're building something very un-HTTP-like. An HTTP request should not take more than a few milliseconds to answer, and HTTP requests shouldn't be interdependent; if you need to execute calculations which take rather long, either try to speed them up by changing your architecture/model/caching/whatever, or treat it explicitly as long-running jobs **which can be controlled through an HTTP interface.** That means that "a job" is a "physical resource" which can be queried through HTTP. You create the resource through a POST request:

```
POST /tasks
Content-Type: application/json

{"some": "parameters", "go": "here"}
```

```
{"resource": "/tasks/42"}
```

Then you can query for the status of the task:

```
GET /tasks/42
```

```
{"status": "pending"}
```

And eventually get results:

```
GET /tasks/42
```

```
{"status": "done", "results": [...]}
```

When you POST a new task which supersedes the old one, your backend can cancel the old task in any way it sees fit; the resource would then return a status of "cancelled" or similar. Your client would simply not query the old resource again after starting a new task.

Even if your client queries the resource once every second, it will still use less resources on the server (one connection being open for a solid 10 seconds vs. 10 connections open for 200ms within the same timeframe), especially if you apply some intelligent caching to it. This is also much more scalable as you can scale the task backend independently of the HTTP frontend to it, and the HTTP frontend can be scaled trivially to multiple servers and load balancers.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post a solution from @Drizzt1991:

> Hey there, Artem. Quite a strange requirement you have there.
>   Understand that if 1 client is using a socket with keep-alive it's not really possible to see the next request, before answering the first one. This is how HTTP works, it expects result before sending another request.
>   So your case will only work if client will operate on 2 separate sockets, but again, you need to assert, that 2 sockets from the same client will be routed on the same machine. By practice this does not really work that good with failover and stuff. Basically it will be a Stateful API.
>   Even if you do all that, not all libraries support cancellation. Traditional relational DB's will only ignore the result, but will still process the pending query. It's OK if you do complex stuff as Graph traversal and you have a lot of steps, that can be cancelled thou.
>
> But if you assert, that client uses a pool of sockets and they are routed to the same machine and the requests benefit from cancellation, something like this should do the trick:

```
import asyncio
import random

from aiohttp import web


def get_session_id(request):
    # I don't know how you do session management, so left it out
    return ""


async def handle(request):
    session_id = get_session_id(request)
    request['tr_id'] = tr_id = int(random.random() * 1000000)

    running_tasks = request.app['running_tasks']
    if session_id in running_tasks and not running_tasks[session_id].done():
        running_tasks[session_id].cancel()
        del running_tasks[session_id]

    current_task = asyncio.ensure_future(_handle_impl(request))
    running_tasks[session_id] = current_task

    try:
        resp = await current_task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Cancelled request", tr_id)
        resp = web.Response(text="Cancelled {}".format(tr_id))
    finally:
        if running_tasks[session_id] is current_task:
            del running_tasks[session_id]
    return resp


async def _handle_impl(request):
    tr_id = request['tr_id']
    print("Start request", tr_id)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Finished request", tr_id)
    return web.Response(text="Finished {}".format(tr_id))


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
app.router.add_get('/{name}', handle)

app['running_tasks'] = {}

web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```